# How to retrieve Array from Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a column in my Parse class which is of type Array, as the image below shows:

[image]

It is an ArrayList of Strings that I stored before.
I want to retrieve that array into my another activity in my Android application. I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this. Currently, my approach is  to make a class that extends the ParseObject class and then make a getter method to retrieve it, as follows:

```
import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@ParseClassName("Workout")
public class ParseWorkout extends ParseObject{

    public ArrayList<String> getReps() {
        return get("Reps");
    }
}
```

However, its giving me this error:

[image]

What is the proper way to retrieve the stored Array objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getList("Reps")` method:

```
@ParseClassName("Workout")
public class ParseWorkout extends ParseObject{

    public List<String> getReps() {
        return getList("Reps");
    }
}
```

API Reference (moved): http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getList(java.lang.String)